# Update problem and Ubuntu error

Tags: updates

Whenever I try to open system tools or setting or when I make a reboot.. a notification appears saying:

> Ubuntu is experiencing an internal error

and also there is a permanent message on the top right:

> An error occurred.......this usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

I don't want to make update, because I cannot reopen server again. I lost much server data before like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make backups to avoid losing data, then update your system like the error messages are suggesting. All possible fixes will involve doing that first.